# Remmina Remote Desktop Client installed?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, remmina

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I was searching for a file in Dash when I saw 'Remmina Remote Desktop Client'. Judging by the icon, it doesn't look like default software. I'm the only one who uses this pc so I want to ask is RRDC automatically installed or did I install it by accident?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is installed by default, though I'm not sure what you judged from the icon.

```
$ apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep remmina
  Recommends: remmina
```

It is the default remote desktop/VNC client on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was a little bit worried. What I meant with the icon was that a lot of default programs have a purple-ish icon. Also, I already found 'Desktop Sharing' which is a default program,  and I thought it was the same as RRDC, but I don't have a lot of knowledge about this kind of software so I wasn't sure.

Comment: @KlokPok Desktop Sharing is managing the settings related to desktop sharing, not an actual client for it. I think you have messed up the icons. Remmina's icon should look like [this](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSjCU78MGYzWTLsNOS5tOVlF0ZMJCeFtQF7JhntUPlR-rv7k1JVMg)